# Detect application close

Tags: xcode, swift

Is there any way to detect if the application fully closes? Not only minimize but fully close application? I want to run a code that delete a NSUserDefault key when the application closes. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

In your AppDelegate there's a method:

```
applicationWillTerminate
```

You can probably take care of what you need to there.